# Dirichlet integral's history

Tags: mathematics, calculus, dirichlet

I was calculating the so-called [Dirichlet Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_integral),

$$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x} \text{d} x$$

and then I wondered about his name and history:

1. Why it has the name of [Dirichlet](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Gustav_Lejeune_Dirichlet)?
2. When was it first calculated?
3. In what context it showed up for the first time and from which interests it needed (if so) to be evaluated?

I don't know any resources (except for Stack Exchange) for researching this questions, and I haven't found anything related to them after surfing along the first 4 pages of results of "dirichlet integral history" in Google.

Does anybody know anything about its history or where to find information about it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It arose in [Dirichlet’s famous proof](https://archive.org/stream/diepartiellendi04webegoog#page/n55) of the convergence of Fourier series ([1829](https://books.google.com/books?id=oZpGAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA157), [p. 161](https://books.google.com/books?id=oZpGAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA161)),<sup>1</sup> then again in his “discontinuous factor” method to compute integrals ([1839](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k2967c/f160); [1904](https://www.emis.de/cgi-bin/JFM-item?35.0312.01), pp. [193-195](https://archive.org/stream/glejeunedirichle00lejeuoft#page/193), [353-385](https://archive.org/stream/glejeunedirichle00lejeuoft#page/353))<sup>2</sup> and in his “jump function” proof of the central limit theorem (1846; [2011](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2743162), [pp. 69-74](https://books.google.com/books?id=v7kTwafIiPsC&pg=PA70)).<sup>3</sup>

Apparently first evaluated by Euler in *De valoribus integralium a termino variabilis $x = 0$ usque ad $x = \infty$ extensorum* (1781; 1794, pp. 337–[345](https://books.google.com/books?id=LmwyliFqN7cC&pg=PA345); 1932, pp. [lxiii](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k69676/f65), 217–[227](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k69676/f297));<sup>4</sup> Dirichlet’s uses are also foreshadowed in Fourier ([1822, pp. 510-512](https://archive.org/stream/oeuvresdefourier01four#page/510)),<sup>5</sup> Poisson ([1824, p. 276](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?u=1&id=nyp.33433090910104&num=273)), Bessel ([1838](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1838AN.....15..369B), [p. 393](https://books.google.com/books?id=eFY_AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA393)).

Incidentally, I suspect that calling it ***the*** Dirichlet integral is a misnomer introduced by Wikipedia: so far as I can tell, none of the below-quoted authors do that. Rather, they call *any* integral of the form $\smash{\int_0^\infty f(x)\frac{\sin kx}{x}dx}$ (including of course this one) ***a*** Dirichlet integral.

**References in English:**
<sup>1</sup>[Dirichlet](https://doi.org/10.11429/subutsukiji1885b.3.249) p. 255, [Carslaw](http://archive.org/stream/introductiontoth00carsrich#page/200) pp. 200-212, [Bottazzini](http://ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=860945) pp. 190-196, [Roy](http://ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2807493) pp. 417-421, [Petrovic](https://books.google.com/books?id=oUfBAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA238&lpg=PA233&vq=Dirichlet) Prob. 9.2.14. <sup>2</sup>[Price](https://archive.org/stream/atreatiseoninfi06pricgoog#page/n442) pp. 399-410. <sup>3</sup>[Fischer](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2743162) pp. 44-52. <sup>4</sup>[Euler](https://arxiv.org/abs/0705.4640) p. 7. <sup>5</sup>[Fourier](https://archive.org/stream/analyticaltheory00four#page/439) §423.

Comment: An entire paper actually exists: *Fischer, Hans*, [**The history of the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx$: a history of analysis in a nutshell**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00591-007-0016-0), Math. Semesterber. 54, No. 1, 13-30 (2007). [ZBL1118.01014](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1118.01014).

Comment: I don't speak french nor german, I can't understand the sources. What was being proved exactly in that "Dirichlet’s famous proof of the convergence of Fourier series"?

Comment: @ElíasGuisado I have tried to add references to English expositions / translations.